# Ionic Application crashes loading InAppBrowser

Tags: android, ionic, cordova

estoy haciendo una aplicacion en ionic para visualizar una web responsive, eso es todo. si pongo un boton en la app para navegar a traves de un inappbrowser funciona perfectamente, pero no sé como hacerlo para que navegue al abrir la aplicación ya que si lo pongo en el evento ngOnInit casca.

No sé que puede ser, aquí teneis el código.
No sé que puede ser, aquí teneis el código.
No sé que puede ser, aquí teneis el código.
No sé que puede ser, aquí teneis el código.
No sé que puede ser, aquí teneis el código.
No sé que puede ser, aquí teneis el código.

```js
 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage    {
 

  //constructor() {}
  constructor(private inAppBrowser : InAppBrowser, private platform : Platform) {

  }

  subscription: any

  ngOnInit () {
    // this.launchSite();
    //this.inAppBrowser.create(`http://apache.org`, `_blank`);

  }

  launchSite(){
    this.inAppBrowser.create(`https://www.google.es`,`_self`);
  }



  exitApp(){
    navigator['app'].exitApp();
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
        navigator['app'].exitApp();
        });


  }

ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

 

}
```

```html
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row justify-content-center>
    <ion-col align-self-center size-md="6" size-lg="5" size-xs="12">
      <div text-center>
        <h4>WebApp</h4>
        <p>Simple app</p>
      </div>



  <div padding>
     <ion-button size="large" (click)='launchSite()' expand="block">Launch</ion-button>
     <ion-button size="large" (click)='exitApp()' color="danger" expand="block">Exit</ion-button>
  </div>

</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hola el error indicado dice que las declaraciones import deben aparecer antes de cualquier otro código. ¿Revisaste que no haya nada encima? la sección de código que muestras insinúa que podría haber algo antes.

Comment: No hay necesidad de preguntar en inglés pues estás en so en español, por favor edita y corrige ese punto